# Read in values from scanner until i click enter

Tags: java

```
while(sc.hasNextInt()){                                 
  int i = sc.nextInt();
  innerArr.add(i);           
}
```

I have a scanner named "sc" which takes in input. I would like to be able to type "1 2 3 4 5" followed by "Enter". This will let my code break out of the while loop and carry on the other codes below. However, when i type "1 2 3 4 5" and "Enter", my code does not break out of the loop. It only breaks out when i type in something like "1 2 3 4 5 a". how do i fix this?

Comment: You could [read in one line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) from your scanner and then [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` hide the delimiter from you (which is what `Scanner` should do) your code would not be able to tell the difference between end-user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> vs. space between the numbers.

However, you can read `nextLine()`, and convert it to an array of `int`s in one go:

```
var line = sc.nextLine();
int[] innerArr = Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```